# How Highlight IFC Model in Three.js with Raycasting

Tags: javascript, three.js, ifc

I want  to create a IFC Loader with Three.js and i loaded the IFC file in the scene using Web-IFC-Three but how can i highlight the ifc model on mouse hover and get attributed of that part with three.js

i have tried using raycast in three.js but getting some error when try to highlight that model

Comment: Hi Aditya, Welcome to stackoverflow. You need to share the code and error details for community to help on this.